# How do I fix 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined' in Crafty.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, craftyjs

So for our project my group and I are trying to program a game. The objective of the game is to change the color of the other player's ship.

For example: If Player 1's ship is colored Red, and Player 2's ship is colored green, each bullet from player 1 that hits Player 2 will slowly turn player 2 from red to green. This is done by the help of bit shifts that is explained below. So for the majority of the time we have been encountering the Uncaught Type Error and we cannot find what the problem is. This file uses : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js
and
http://craftyjs.com/release/0.4.2/crafty.js
as dependencies to help run the program.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

Crafty.init(); 
Crafty.canvas(); 



Crafty.load(["player.png"], function() {
    //splice the spritemap
    Crafty.sprite(1, "player.png", 
    {
        ship: [0,0]
    });

    //start the main scene when loaded
    Crafty.scene("main");
});

    //player entity for player 1
   var player1 = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, Controls, Collision, Color, ship, player")
        .attr({move: {left: false, right: false, up: false, down: false}, xspeed: 0, yspeed: 0, decay: 0.9, h: 50, w: 50, radius: 50, start_time: 0, x: Crafty.viewport.width / 2, y: Crafty.viewport.height / 2 })
        .color('red')
        .bind("keydown", function(e) {
            //on keydown, set the move booleans
            if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.RIGHT_ARROW) {
                this.move.right = true;
            } else if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.LEFT_ARROW) {
                this.move.left = true;
            } else if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.UP_ARROW) {
                this.move.up = true;
            } else if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.SPACE) {
                var d = new Date();
                this.start_time = d.getTime();
            }
        }).bind("keyup", function(e) {
            //on key up, set the move booleans to false
            if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.RIGHT_ARROW) {
                this.move.right = false;
            } else if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.LEFT_ARROW) {
                this.move.left = false;
            } else if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.UP_ARROW) {
                this.move.up = false;
            } else if(e.keyCode === Crafty.keys.SPACE) {
                var time = new Date().getTime();
                if((time - this.start_time) >= 5000)
                    var charge = 5;

                //else
                //var charge = (time - this.start_time)/1000;

                Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Color, bullet")
                    .attr({
                        x: this._x, 
                        y: this._y, 
                        w: 1.5, 
                        h: 1.5,

                        rotation: this._rotation, 
                        xspeed: 20 * Math.sin(this._rotation / 57.3), 
                        yspeed: 20 * Math.cos(this._rotation / 57.3),



                    })
                    .color('red')
                    .bind("enterframe", function() {    
                        this.x += this.xspeed;
                        this.y -= this.yspeed;

                        //destroy if it goes out of bounds
                        if(this._x > Crafty.viewport.width || this._x < 0 || this._y > Crafty.viewport.height || this._y < 0) {
                            this.destroy();
                        }
                    });
            }


        }).bind("enterframe", function() {
            if(this.move.right) this.rotation += 5;
            if(this.move.left) this.rotation -= 5;

            //acceleration and movement vector
            var vx = Math.sin(this._rotation * Math.PI / 180) * 0.3,
                vy = Math.cos(this._rotation * Math.PI / 180) * 0.3;

            //if the move up is true, increment the y/xspeeds
            if(this.move.up) {
                this.yspeed -= vy;
                this.xspeed += vx;
            } else {
                //if released, slow down the ship
                this.xspeed *= this.decay;
                this.yspeed *= this.decay;
            }

            //move the ship by the x and y speeds or movement vector
            this.x += this.xspeed;
            this.y += this.yspeed;

            //if ship goes out of bounds, put him back
            if(this._x > Crafty.viewport.width) {
                this.x = -64;
            }
            if(this._x < -64) {
                this.x =  Crafty.viewport.width;
            }
            if(this._y > Crafty.viewport.height) {
                this.y = -64;
            }
            if(this._y < -64) {
                this.y = Crafty.viewport.height;
            }

        }).collision()
        .onHit("bullet", function(e) {
        //basically the bullet is color A and hits ship B and changes the color to ship A
        //bullets are based on ship A 
        //red to green
            if(e.color() != 'red'){
                /*
            if(e.color() === "#FF0000" && this.start_color === "#00FF00") 
            {
                this.color = this.color + ("#010000" - "#000001") * e.radius;

                    //red to blue
            } else if(e.color === "#FF0000" && this.color === "#0000FF") 
            {
                this.color = this.color + ("#010000" - "#000001") * e.radius;

            }
            */
            //green to red
            if(e.color() === "#00FF00") 
            {
                this.color(this.color() + ("#010000" - "#000001") * e.radius);

            }
            /*
            //green to blue
            else if(e.color === "#00FF00" && this.color === "#0000FF") 
            {
                this.color = this.color + ("#010000" - "#000001") * e.radius;

            }
            */
            //blue to red
            else if(e.color() === "#0000FF") 
            {
                this.color(this.color() + ("#010000" - "#000001") * e.radius);
            }
            /*
            //blue to green
            else (e.color === "#0000FF" && this.color === "#00FF00") 
            { 
                this.color = this.color + ("#010000" - "#000001") * e.radius;
            }
            */
            if(this.color() === e.color()){
                   Crafty.scene("end");
            }

            this.xspeed = this.xspeed - .1*e.xspeed;
            this.yspeed = this.yspeed - .1*e.yspeed;
            e[0].obj.destroy();
        }

        }).onHit("player", function(e) {

                var diff = "#ff" - (this.color()>>4);
                this.color(this.color() + (.2*diff) << 4);
                if(e.color() === "green") {
                    this.color(this.color() - (.2*diff) << 2);
                }
                else {
                    this.color(this.color() - .2*diff);
                }


            this.xspeed = this.xspeed - e.xspeed;
            this.yspeed = this.yspeed - e.yspeed;
        });

});
```

EDIT: I managed to take out the comments and some irrelevant code

Comment: Can you take out irrelevant code? That's a lot of code to look for one error

Comment: I took out some of the code, hope that helps!

Comment: The `color` stuff looks fishy to me. The [api docs](http://craftyjs.com/api/Color.html) only mention it being used as a function for setting the color. No property-like access, nor getter function.

Comment: Additionally the events are case sensitive `"enterframe"`, and `"keydown"` should never be fired. Try `"EnterFrame"` and `"KeyDown"` instead.

Comment: You should be able to figure out the offending code in your browser's developer tools. Navigate up the call stack to find out which line causes the error. Be sure to use the non-minified version of Crafty.

Comment: I fixed the error by basically making a new read to main in the html file and deleting the $(document) prompt. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by basically making a new read to main in the html file and deleting the $(document) prompt. Thanks for all your help!